# Call two web service methods simultaneously(parallel)

Tags: c#, .net

I am new in .Net development..........

I want to call two web service methods simultaneously(parallel) using c# code from the application, web service is built as a separate application. In my application, one web service method should get called & it is not needed to wait for the response, then another service method should get called & it is not needed to wait for the response, but after calling both of these service methods, I need to wait for the respond for first method & as per the result I need to proceed ahead, what is the best way to perform this?

Comment: Do the web service methods have `async` versions (returning `Task<T>` rather than `T` for some type `T`)?

Comment: Look in to `Task.WhenAny` example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx

Comment: Have you tried Async= "true"?. link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms230194(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I am calling built web service methods from my C# application, my application is not the web service application, just I am consuming the web service methods from my application.